# i'm having trouble with a while-loop that I just can't figure out why it won't work as desired

Tags: c++, vector, while-loop

Made a while-loop and I'm not getting the result I think I should be getting.

I've done a little debugging and got nothing. Visual Studio 2019 is saying I'm good to go.

```
int main()
{
    double num_enter;
    vector<double> nums(0);
    while (cin >> num_enter)
    {
    nums.push_back(num_enter);
    sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
    if (num_enter < nums.front())
    {
    cout << num_enter << " is the smallest one yet.\n" << endl;
    }
    else if (num_enter > nums.back())
    {
    cout << num_enter << " is the biggest one yet.\n" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want a while(cin>>enter_num) loop to read num_enter and do a vector.push_back(num_enter) followed by the vector sort function and have it out put if the number has been "the smallest yet" or "the biggest yet" but its not working. could you point out what I'm doing wrong? I'm new be gental.

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: I tried to fix the format with an online code formatter but I think you are missing a `}`.

Comment: Consider adding echo trace, i.e. cout the nums vector after each sort.

Comment: Your program is testing for whether `num_enter` is smaller/larger than all the sorted vector elements seen so far, which includes `num_enter` itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one number in the vector. None of the conditions are met, if you enter one, one is not greater than one or less than one, hence it is not printing anything because you are not handling that case. Add an else block that prints if the numbers are equal then hopefully it will be clear to you why that is happening.

try this

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double num_enter;
    vector<double> nums(0);

    while (cin >> num_enter) {
    nums.push_back(num_enter);

    //sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
         // Lets say you entered 1
        // 1 < 1 -> false
        if (num_enter < nums.front()) 
        {
            cout << num_enter << " is the smallest one yet.\n" << endl;
        }

        // 1 > 1 -> false
        else if (num_enter > nums.back())
        {
            cout << num_enter << " is the biggest one yet.\n" << endl;

        } 
        else // 1 == 1 
        {
            cout << "Numbers are equal" << endl;   
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of vector:

vector vectorName(size);

vector nums(0)

In your code nums is a vector of size zero.

Vector is a dynamic array.

Array of zero size is meaningless.

Check this [link](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.techiedelight.com/initialize-vector-cpp/amp/) to see different ways of declaring vector.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you code order should be changed, the if-elseif-else block should be put in front of the push_back and sort,

or if you really want to maintain the order, if-elseif-else should be corrected like if(num_enter == nums.front()) ... else if(num_enter == nums.back())... else,

only then you can know if your input number has been the biggest or smallest yet.

And initialize like vector`<double>`nums(0) is little weird, just using vector`<double>`nums is fine